# Drawing a line in Mono for android

Tags: c#, android, drawing, xamarin.android

I' m trying to draw a simple point (x,y) to point (x2,y2) line with mono for android. I'm trying to do this by using the Canvas.drawline() function. Here is what I have so far:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{        
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    Paint P = new Paint();
    Canvas C = new Canvas();

    P.Color = Color.Red;
    P.StrokeWidth = 2;           

    C.DrawLine(100, 100, 200, 200, P);
}
```

This should draw a line between the points 100,100 to 200,200 but for some reason, it doesn' t draw a line at all. So I could use some help. Is there something wrong in this code?

Comment: How is the canvas connected to the screen? I don't know anything about Mono, but it looks like you aren't viewing the Canvas itself. You should add it as a child of the main container, or something.

Comment: most likely you have to set canvas to content of some container.

Comment: Oké i somewhat figured that out myself. But i have no idea how to add visual elements in mono for android, because it doesn't contain any designer interface. So i figured if i do it by just making a new Canvas, it would automatically place it on the main view. apparently it doesn't. So if someone know how i do that. that would make my day ;)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a `Canvas` hooked up to the screen. You can do this by subclassing [Android.Views.View](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aAndroid.Views.View) and overriding [View.OnDraw](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aAndroid.Views.View.OnDraw(Android.Graphics.Canvas)).

For example, see the [ApiDemo Layers sample](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/ApiDemo/Graphics/Layers.cs#L38).